# Filling and painting bowls

Tags: combinatorics

I only know basic things about combinatorics, but I encountered a problem.

You have 60 bowls. Then you do the following:

1. Fill 30 bowls with one ball
2. Fill 20 bowls with two balls
3. Fill 10 bowls with three balls
4. Take away n bowls
5. Paint 4 bowls red
6. Paint 4 bowls blue

(The balls look the same, n is a natural number or zero and the bowls are numbered 1;2;3;...;60)

My question is: How many combinations are possible for n stolen bowls? I'm able to calculate how many combinations are possible after step 3. For me it's also possible to calculate how many combinations there are for n = 0; but I have problems with n > 0.

The problem is so weird, because it represents a much more complex problem in my AI and I would have to explain a much bigger problem here if I wouldn't do this like this. It's like I can select 5 people out of 10 or I can select 5 balls out off 10.

Answer (score 0):

I can not understand your problem, why does step 4 depend on other steps? You have 60 bowls and you want to take away n of then... what is the role of balls and paintings here?!

Comment: I didn't mean that step 4 depends on other steps, but I need to be able to calculate step 4 in order to solve the problem.

Comment: So if you ignore balls and paintings does the solution differ? selecting n bowls from 60 bowls is number of n-combinations of 60. If n is variable you can compute the sum of 1-combinations, 2-combinations .... up to 60-combinations of 60. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I think I've got your point. What I meant with combinations is not just the combination of the bowls, but also the combination of paintings and balls. So if you take away 1 bowl, you have more possibilities to paint the bowls left than you have if you take 5 bowls away.